# button on uiTableViewCell that updates entire tableView

Tags: uitableview, swift

I have one class BrandOfCarTableViewCell: UITableViewCell which has labels and buttons.
One button increases the number on label, and second one decreases it.
In addition, I have a second class class TypeOfTransportTableViewController: UITableViewController which has all operations with a tableView

I need to give tableViewController the indexOf cell where a button was clicked.   I also need to pass the value of the label (quantity)

How can I do that by using the Swift language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic structure of your code should be as follows.

```
protocol BrandOfCarTableViewCellDelegate {
 func updateLabelCountWithValue:(cellIndex: Int ,newValue :Int)
}

class BrandOfCarTableViewCell: UITableViewCell  {
 //This class can have your label and the two buttons
 var cellIndex: Int = 0
 var delegate: BrandOfCarTableViewCellDelegate?

 func setUpCellWithIndex:(index: Int)
  self.cellIndex = index
 }

 @IBAction func buttonTapped() {
 //Call the delegate
 }
}

class TypeOfTransportTableViewController: UITableViewController, BrandOfCarTableViewCellDelegate {

 func updateLabelCountWithValue:(cellIndex: Int ,newValue :Int) {
 }
}
```

Comment: Hello Kumar, thanks for answering. 1) How should I cal setUpCellWithIndex function? I set indexes in TypeOfTransportTableViewController at cellForRowAtIndexPath with cell.cellIndex = indexPath.row 2) How can I call delegate? is it in this way delegate. updateLabelCountWithValue(cellIndex: Int ,newValue :Int)

Answer (score 0):

Lots of Thanks for KUMAR!!!

```
 protocol BrandOfCarTableViewCellDelegate{
func updateLabelWithValueAtIndex(cellIndex:Int, newValue: Int)
}
class BrandOfCarTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var delegate:BrandOfCarTableViewCellDelegate?
@IBAction func btnPlus(sender: AnyObject) {

    cellIndex = btnPlusOutlet.tag

    counter = counter + 1

    // call the delegate
    delegate?.updateLabelWithValueAtIndex(cellIndex!, newValue: counter)
}


@IBAction func btnMinus() {

    cellIndex = btnPlusOutlet.tag

    if counter >= 1 {
         counter = counter - 1
    }
    else{ return }

    // call the delegate
    delegate?.updateLabelWithValueAtIndex(cellIndex!, newValue: counter)
}
}

class TypeOfTransportTableViewController: UITableViewController {

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BrandOfCarCell",     forIndexPath: indexPath) as BrandOfCarTableViewCell

    cell.delegate = self
    cell.btnPlusOutlet.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.labelQty.text = String(arrayBrandsOfTransport[indexPath.row].qty)
}


func updateLabelWithValueAtIndex(cellIndex:Int, newValue: Int){
//        println("table view controller cell index: \(cellIndex)" )
//        println("the newvalue is \(newValue)")
        arrayBrandsOfTransport[cellIndex].qty = newValue
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

I just updated the value of array where I keep all values and reload the table!  Thanks Kumar

Comment: I could have written the entire code, but I wanted you to figure out the remaining part. Updating the tag of a button may not be a best practice. Instead call a method cell. setUpCellWithIndex() with the required index.

Comment: Now you'll face another issue, since the function is not public. Now I want you to figure that out :)